# Display star according to value in fivestar

Tags: rating

I have custom values of user rating eg: 20,30,40,..100. how can i display as star in fivestar.I am using fivestar and voting module.

Comment: You can display average of all the votes. I would like to whether you are displaying five stars for rating or ten stars ?

Comment: in my situation i am getting the value of current user vote as 20,30,40,..100 now I just simply wants to show stars i.e convert these values in stars.is there is any hook or anything else.